# Iss with Distinct values

Tags: php, mysql

I have some php code here that is supposed to show the unique/disctinct values from a field called 'Collections'. I have successfully connected to my database elsewhere. When this php code executes, the browser gives me an "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in mypage.php on line 20"

```
         $id = isset($_GET['id'])?(int)$_GET['id']:0; // if $_GET['id'] exists, return it as an integer, otherwise use a sentinel, id's usually start with 1, so 0 works

       if ($id!=0): 
// I assume this is a specific news item meaning you know it's ONE result
$query = 'SELECT * DISTINCT (Collections) FROM Audios LIMIT 40'; // so try to use limit     1, no need to add extra steps in the database lookup
    else: 
$query = 'SELECT * DISTINCT (Collections) FROM Audios ORDER BY Collections DESC LIMIT 40'; 
    endif;

   $result = mysql_query($query);
;
// now loop through the results ***(This is Line 20)***
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
// and use'em however you wish
echo '

 <div>

  <li><a href="#">'.$row['Collections'].'</a></p>
</div>
 '; 
   }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT (Collections) FROM Audios ORDER BY Collections DESC LIMIT 40
```

Remove the * in both queries.

Comment: lol thanks, this worked....I think I need a break from staring at the machine. Then again I doubt I would have fixed it on my own